# VLOOKUP from another spreadsheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a master spreadsheet that analyzes records from another spreadsheet with rows going all the way up to 1.4 million.

Below are the relevant pieces from the code:

```vb
    Sub Whyamidoingthis()

    Dim USISINLfp As String
    Dim ISINL As String
    Dim echeck As String
    Dim wUSISIN As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Result As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set OutShVar = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("in1")
    ISINL = "CONSOLIDATED - Country_Of_Incorp_US_2019-03-01 (Consolidated).xlsx"

    USISINLfp = "W:\Product Platforms\ISIN- CUSIP Country of Incorporation\March 2019\"

    Workbooks.Open (USISINLfp & ISINL)
    Set wUSISIN = Workbooks(ISINL)

    With Result
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

     'US Security 1

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        With Result
            echeck = Trim(.Range("O" & i))
            If echeck = "" Then
                .Range("P" & i & ":Q" & i).Value = "N"
            Else
                .Range("P" & i).Value = "=ifna(vlookup(O" & i & "," & ISINL & "First Sheet'!$B:$C,2,false)," & Chr(34) & "N" & Chr(34) & ")"
                .Range("Q" & i).Value = "=ifna(vlookup(O" & i & "," & ISINL & "Second Sheet'!$B:$C,2,false)," & Chr(34) & "N" & Chr(34) & ")"
                'Debug.Print "=ifna(vlookup(O" & i & "," & ISINL & "Second Sheet'!$B:$C,2,0)," & Chr(34) & "N" & Chr(34) & ")"
            End If

      'US Security 2
            echeck = Trim(.Range("S" & i))
            If echeck = "" Then
                .Range("T" & i & ":U" & i).Value = "N"
            Else
                .Range("T" & i).Value = "=ifna(vlookup(S" & i & "," & ISINL & "First Sheet'!$A:$C,3,false)," & Chr(34) & "N" & Chr(34) & ")"
                .Range("U" & i).Value = "=ifna(vlookup(S" & i & "," & ISINL & "Second Sheet'!$A:$C,3,false)," & Chr(34) & "N" & Chr(34) & ")"
            End If

        End With
    Next I

    If Not wUSISIN Is Nothing Then wUSISIN.Close savechanges:=False

    End Sub
```

The code is getting stuck at the following line:

```
.Range("T" & i).Value = "=ifna(vlookup(S" & i & "," & ISINL & "First Sheet'!$A:$C,3,false)," & Chr(34) & "N" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Whenever a result is found and the error is application defined error.

Comment: Are you trying to set a *value* or a *formula*? If the latter, use `.Range("P" & i).Formula` rather than `.Range("P" & i).Value` (not that this is the problem here)

Comment: Formula, changed it. Good point. Still giving me an error though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
"=ifna(vlookup(O" & i & ",'[" & ISINL & "]First Sheet'!$B:$C,2,false)," & Chr(34) & "N" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

This places square brackets around the workbook name and single quotes around the workbook-worksheet combo. See [this tutorial](https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-from-another-workbook) about using VLOOKUP from another workbook.